# replacing bytes in C data

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
unsigned char* originaldata = (unsigned char*)malloc(50);
strcpy((char*)originalData,"12345       7");

unsigned char* replacingData = (unsigned char*)malloc(9);
strcpr((char*)replacingData,"11111111");

memset(replacingData,6,6);
```

Then, I want to replace the data from position 6 till end of originalData with replacingData.

How could i do this in C code?

Comment: Have you tried strcpy with a pointer+6?

Comment: I.e., you're trying to replace 44 bytes with 9 bytes? What's the `memset` supposed to do? And shouldn't `strcpr` be `strcpy`?

Comment: you want `orginalData` to become `"12345111111117"`?

Comment: ur replacingData contains same repetition of characters or it can have any string? if its repetition y don't u take it as single character data only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(originalData+6, replacingData, strlen(originalData)-6)
```

Although, it should be noted that this makes the assumption that `originalData` is always greater than 6 characters long and that `replacingData` is longer than 6 characters shorter than `originalData`.

Comment: Since `replacingData` is 9 bytes long, this reads beyond the end of a `malloc`'d buffer and causes UB.

Comment: Not in this case as `strlen(originalData)` is 13 characters in the example shown above meaning this copies 7 bytes from `replacingData`. Anything further is covered by the caveats I put in the text. Admittedly, the answer is not hugely general but then the question makes little reference to the end goal so it is hard to generalise from it.

Comment: What does the length of `replacingData` have to do with it?

Comment: As larsmans was driving at if `replacingData` is too short you will copy past the end of it and cause undefined behaviour (C way of saying anything can happen, mostly likely junk will be copied into `originalData`)

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed the `strlen` call. @CharlesKeepax: "most likely", yes, but the program could also segfault.